# Facebook integration for Android: Customize dialogs provided by the facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

My app needs to get some permissions from the user. 
To do that, I am using a LoginButton from the Facebook SDK, which fires an intent, which is handled by the official Facebook app, which generates a dialog ('Do you want to give this app these permissions? OK/Cancel'), and whatever the interaction with it returns to my activity.

Cool. Is there a way or mechanism to somehow minimalistically change the style of the dialog that the facebook app provides? The dialog theme, maybe? 
(Definitive and argumented negative answer is also an answer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog shown is a WebDialog. No api to control it. The theme applied on it is : DEFAULT_THEME = android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar. There is no direct api or way to change the theme unless you want to change the core sdk. which would then make it hard to manage.

Comment: Just to be clear,we are  talking about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/ (that's what I am asking about, might as well rephrase the question) It just doesn't look exactly like a web dialog.